# Unity Hub на astra linux

Tags: unity3d, astra-linux

Как установить движок Unity на ОС astra Linux? Пробовал использовать .deb для Ubuntu, но не помогло. В интернете ответа тоже не нашел

Comment: "Не помогло" - это что значит? Ошибка при установке, не запускается после установки, или что?